# redux-localstorage implementation error: Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `store` of type `function` supplied to `Provider`, expected `object`

Tags: reactjs, redux, local-storage, react-redux

I'm currently implementing [redux-localstorage](https://github.com/elgerlambert/redux-localstorage)

but I'm encountering the following error: Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `store` of type `function` supplied to `Provider`, expected `object`

Here's my index.js file - what am I missing here?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { compose, createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import persistState from 'redux-localstorage'

import App from './components/app';
import reducers from './reducers';

const logger = createLogger({ collapsed: true });
const enhancer = compose(
  ReduxThunk,
  logger,
  persistState(null, 'redux')
);

const store = createStore(reducers, enhancer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got the signature for `persistState` wrong, try invoking it with no arguments.

https://github.com/elgerlambert/redux-localstorage#persiststatepaths-config

Comment: same error still occurs when no arguments are passed to persistState

Comment: Try adding the default state to `createStore` - `createStore(reducers, {}, enhancer);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide thunk as an argument to the applyMiddleware function:

```
const enhancer = compose(
  applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk),
  applyMiddleware(logger),
  persistState(null, 'redux')
);
```

You'll need to do the same for logger also